# What about variable scopes inside a callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, scope

If I have a callback function within a callback function I can't reach the variables declared inside the first callback.

See example (Uses some jquery):

[my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/botenvouwer/A9GCb/)

Why is this?

Or

What am I doing wrong!?

I am using this in the following:

```
$('<div/>').html(data).find('load').each(function(id, deze) {

        var method = $(deze).attr("method");
        var animate = $(deze).attr("animate");
        var locatie = $(deze).attr("id");
        var html = $(deze).html();

        if(!method){
            method = 'overide';
        }

        if(!locatie){
            error('A002','No loadloc');
        }

        if(!html){
            html = '';
        }

        if(!animate){
            animate = false;
        }
        else if(animate == 'fade'){
            var effectout = 'fade';
            var timeout = 100;
            var optionsout = {
                easing: 'swing'
            };

            var effectin = 'fade';
            var timein = 600;
            var optionsin = {
                easing: 'swing'
            };
        }
        else{
            animate = false;
            error('A006','Animation: "' + animate + '" does not exist');
        }

            //here I make callback or direct function call
        if(animate){
            $('#' + locatie).hide(effectout, optionsout, timeout, load());
        }
        else{
            load();
        }

    function load(){
        console.log('hallo');
        console.log(html);
        if(method == 'overide'){
            $('#' + locatie).html(html);
        }
        else if(method == 'tablerow'){
            var html = $('tr', deze).html();
            $('#' + locatie).html(html);
        }
        else if(method == 'append'){
            $('#' + locatie).append(html);
        }
        else if(method == 'prepend'){
            $('#' + locatie).prepend(html);
        }
        else{
            error('A007','load method: "' + method + '" does not exist');
        }

        if(animate){
            $('#' + locatie).show(effectin, optionsin, timein);
        }
    }

    });
```

Comment: The `something` variable is in scope for the `load` function, so it should work just fine.

Comment: works fine for me 
http://jsfiddle.net/uEUTD/

Comment: Well see update in that context it does not work why not?

Comment: `if(animate = 'fade')`... That should be `==`

Comment: oh didn't see that thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is this?

It is not. You can simply access `something`, it is in the scope of the `load` function that you posted.

> What am I doing wrong!?

You're not passing the `load` function itself as the callback, but it's result - you're immediately calling it (without arguments). You want

```
$('#' + locatie).hide(effectout, optionsout, timeout, load);
//                                                        ^^
```

> ```
> //It seems I can't reach html and other variables here
> console.log(this.html);
> ```

That's not a variable, that's a property of `this` (and the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) points to different things in the different calls). What you want is a simple variable:

```
console.log(html);
```

Same story for `this.locatie` and the others.

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code a bit and I believe this is what you were trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/smerny/2M6k3/

```
var anothercallbackfunctiontriggerthing = function(cb) {
    cb();
}

$('.something').each(function(id, value) {
        var something = 'something';
        var load = function(){
                    // can't reach something here
                    console.log(something);
        }
        anothercallbackfunctiontriggerthing(load);
});
```

As `load()` didn't return anything, I assume you were wanting to pass it as a callback (`load`) and then call it from within `anothercallbackfunctiontriggerthing`. The above code will print "something" for each `.something`.

Comment: No that was just an example I use it this way a lot. Now i pass all variables to function header but its starting to be annoying! So this is not wat I ment I want to know how to access the variables declared inside the first callback.

Comment: Why did you change the function declaration to an anonymous function assignment?

Comment: @sirwilliam No? I don't quite understand. Can you explain a bit better what exactly you are trying to do in that case?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is because the keyword `this` changes meanings within the context of `load()` since you're defining a function using `function load()`. There are several ways of getting around this; here's one:

Before:

```
if(animate){
            $('#' + locatie).hide(effectout, optionsout, timeout, load());
        }
        else{
            load();
        }
```

use

```
var load = (function(el) {
    return function() {
        console.log('hallo');
                //It seems I can't reach html and other variables here
        console.log(el.html);
        if(method == 'overide'){
            $('#' + el.locatie).html(el.html);
        }
        else if(method == 'tablerow'){
            var html = $('tr', deze).html();
            $('#' + el.locatie).html(el.html);
        }
        else if(method == 'append'){
            $('#' + el.locatie).append(el.html);
        }
        else if(method == 'prepend'){
            $('#' + el.locatie).prepend(el.html);
        }
        else{
            error('A007','load method: "' + el.method + '" does not exist');
        }

        if(el.animate){
            $('#' + el.locatie).show(el.effectin, el.optionsin, el.timein);
        }
    };
})(this);
```

What I did there was to change all references to `this` with `el`. And then I injected `this` as `el` by using the following format:

```
load = ( function(el) {  return yourFunction() {...}; })(this);
```

Let me know if that makes sense and if it works for you :)

Comment: Oh sorry for the `this` I tried that in a desperate trial and error attempt. I shall try to implement your suggestion!

Comment: Let know how it goes :)

Comment: I can't get it to work. btw I don't use `this` at all it was a trial and error. see mij updated question where I removed `this`